# How to add a specific field into array of objects in mongodb projection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, aggregation-framework

I've a query like below, It joins 3 tables and projects data, the query looks like this.

```
db.incomedistros.aggregate([
    { 
        $lookup: {
          from: "orders",
          localField: "orderId",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "orderData"
         } 
    },
    { 
        $lookup: {
           from: "settlementsdatas",
           localField: "_id",
           foreignField: "incomeDistroId",
           as: "settlementInfo"
         } 
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$orderData"
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$settlementInfo"
    },
    { 
        $lookup: {
          from: "productvariants",
          localField: "orderData.productIds.id",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "productData"
         } 
    },
    { 
        $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          localField: "orderData.smcId",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "smcData"
         } 
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$smcData"
    },
    {
        $skip: 1
    },
    {
        $limit: 2
    },
    {
        $group: { _id: "$productData._id", documents: { $push: "$$ROOT" } }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": 0,
            "documents._id": 1,
            "documents.createdBy": 1,
            "documents.settlementFor": 1,
            "documents.taxes": 1,
            "documents.deliveryFee": 1,
            "documents.platformFree": 1,
            "documents.productPrice": 1,
            "documents.packingHandlingCharges": 1,
            "documents.convenienceFee": 1,
            "documents.totalAmt": 1,
            "documents.appliedDiscountAmount": 1,
            "documents.appliedCouponId": 1,
            "documents.productData._id": 1,
            "documents.productData.variantName": 1,
            "documents.productData.variantWight": 1,
            "documents.productData.variantWeightUnit": 1,
            "documents.productData.variantPrice": 1,
            "documents.orderData.productIds.quantity": 1,
            "documents.orderData.productIds.id": 1,
            "documents.productData.variantPriceUnit": 1,
            "documents.productData.sku": 1,
            "documents.smcData.mobile": 1,
            "documents.smcData.address": 1,
            "documents.settlementInfo": 1
        }
    }
])
```

and this query projects the output like below,

```
{
    "documents" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("65685f425cb3c6a6c7b14511"),
            "createdBy" : ObjectId("65682bee420ed0783835ed8e"),
            "settlementFor" : "SMC_SETTLEMENT",
            "taxes" : 15.4,
            "deliveryFee" : 0,
            "platformFree" : 2,
            "productPrice" : 308,
            "packingHandlingCharges" : 4,
            "convenienceFee" : 18,
            "totalAmt" : 347.4,
            "appliedDiscountAmount" : null,
            "appliedCouponId" : null,
            "orderData" : {
                "productIds" : [
                    {
                        "id" : ObjectId("652f8bb9c8d17287f5b3ceb4"),
                        "quantity" : 2
                    },
                    {
                        "id" : ObjectId("652f8c3eb6271488577ff7e4"),
                        "quantity" : 3
                    }
                ]
            },
            "settlementInfo" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("65685f425cb3c6a6c7b14513"),
                "settlementFor" : "SMC_SETTLEMENT",
                "orderId" : ObjectId("65685ec6790536a918034030"),
                "incomeDistroId" : ObjectId("65685f425cb3c6a6c7b14511"),
                "driverShare" : 0,
                "gatewayCharges" : 5.210999999999999,
                "smcShare" : 308,
                "platformFree" : 2,
                "taxes" : 15.4
            },
            "productData" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("652f8bb9c8d17287f5b3ceb4"),
                    "variantName" : "Lays Red Chilli",
                    "variantWight" : 530,
                    "variantWeightUnit" : "gm",
                    "variantPrice" : 64,
                    "variantPriceUnit" : "rs",
                    "sku" : "2a58d44e-4d1f-413e-9003-4b95c63cb53c"
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("652f8c3eb6271488577ff7e4"),
                    "variantName" : "Lays White Chilli",
                    "variantWight" : 530,
                    "variantWeightUnit" : "gm",
                    "variantPrice" : 60,
                    "variantPriceUnit" : "rs",
                    "sku" : "fb6c15dd-8764-4ebd-a725-40a5c1e7518b"
                }
            ],
            "smcData" : {
                "mobile" : "8999909999",
                "address" : [
                    {
                        "geoLocation" : {
                            "coordinates" : [ 77.9, 12.9 ],
                            "type" : "Point"
                        },
                        "isDefault" : false,
                        "_id" : ObjectId("652f52c0bec8e373187f1c73"),
                        "fullAddress" : "7th cros naidu layout, Electronic city, Phase II",
                        "fullAddressToLower" : "7th cros naidu layout, electronic city, phase ii",
                        "city" : "Bangalore",
                        "state" : "Karnataka",
                        "pinCode" : "560100",
                        "landMark" : "NY First Food",
                        "buildingName" : "Cat House 2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

now the problem is `documents.orderData.productIds.id` is equivalent to `documents.productData._id` now i need an output where I can see the value of `documents.orderData.productIds.quantity` into every object of `documents.productData` where the id and _id is matching.

Please find the sample data of those three collections,

**incomedistros**

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "65685f425cb3c6a6c7b14511"
  },
  "createdBy": {
    "$oid": "65682bee420ed0783835ed8e"
  },
  "settlementFor": "SMC_SETTLEMENT",
  "orderId": {
    "$oid": "65685ec6790536a918034030"
  },
  "taxes": 15.4,
  "deliveryFee": 0,
  "platformFree": 2,
  "productPrice": 308,
  "packingHandlingCharges": 4,
  "convenienceFee": 18,
  "totalAmt": 347.4,
  "appliedDiscountAmount": null,
  "appliedCouponId": null
}]
```

**settlements**

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "65685f425cb3c6a6c7b14513"
  },
  "settlementFor": "SMC_SETTLEMENT",
  "orderId": {
    "$oid": "65685ec6790536a918034030"
  },
  "incomeDistroId": {
    "$oid": "65685f425cb3c6a6c7b14511"
  },
  "driverShare": 0,
  "gatewayCharges": 5.210999999999999,
  "smcShare": 308,
  "platformFree": 2,
  "taxes": 15.4
}]
```

**orders**

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "65685ec6790536a918034030"
  },
  "pickUpPoint": {
    "geoLocation": {
      "coordinates": [
        77.71,
        12.82
      ],
      "type": "Point"
    },
    "storeAddress": "7th Cross, naidu Layout, EC2",
    "storePinCode": "787654321",
    "storeName": "Chennai Potato Shop"
  },
  "dropAddress": {
    "geoLocation": {
      "coordinates": [
        77.71,
        12.82
      ],
      "type": "Point"
    },
    "isDefault": false,
    "fullAddress": "9th cros naidu layout, Electronic city, Phase II",
    "fullAddressToLower": "9th cros naidu layout, electronic city, phase ii",
    "city": "Bangalore",
    "state": "Karnataka",
    "pinCode": "560100",
    "landMark": "NY First Food",
    "buildingName": "Cat House 2"
  },
  "smcId": {
    "$oid": "6526287bab1f0e46e59f0552"
  },
  "productIds": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "65685ec6790536a918034032"
      },
      "id": {
        "$oid": "652f8bb9c8d17287f5b3ceb4"
      },
      "quantity": 2,
      "variantPrice": 64
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "65685ec6790536a918034031"
      },
      "id": {
        "$oid": "652f8c3eb6271488577ff7e4"
      },
      "quantity": 3,
      "variantPrice": 60
    }
  ],
  "orderReferenceNumber": "06561cfa-8734-4776-9f98-466c0b8a463f",
  "orderDate": {
    "$date": "2023-11-30T10:07:02.923Z"
  },
  "orderId": "O753452680",
  "createdBy": {
    "$oid": "65682bee420ed0783835ed8e"
  },
  "subTotal": 308,
  "deliveryCharges": 0,
  "distanceToTravel": "1 m",
  "distanceToTravelInMeter": 0,
  "eta": "1 min",
  "currency": "INR",
  "orderStatus": "READY_TO_CHECKOUT",
  "paymentMethod": "CREDIT_CARD",
  "collectedTaxAmount": 15.4,
  "platformFee": 2,
  "packingHandlingCharges": 4,
  "convenienceFee": 18,
  "totalAmt": 347.4,
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2023-11-30T10:07:02.931Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2023-11-30T10:07:02.931Z"
  },
  "__v": 0
}]
```

Please help me to find get this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share the sample data for those 3 collections?

Comment: hi @YongShun added, please have a look

Comment: So you want to $filter the documents.orderData.productIds array?

Answer (score 1):

Before the `$group` stage by `"$productData._id"`, you need to add a `$set` stage to update `productData` array by merging each element with the first matching element from the `rderData.productIds` array.

```
{
  $set: {
    productData: {
      $map: {
        input: "$productData",
        as: "pd",
        in: {
          $mergeObjects: [
            "$$pd",
            {
              $first: {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$orderData.productIds",
                  cond: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$pd._id",
                      "$$this.id"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And make sure you add

```
"documents.productData.quantity": 1,
```

in the projection stage.

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/s7GnMB3V4OP)